# How to read data from database and store to an array C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, arrays, dataset

I need to push the result into an array to be able to display in a chart . I am keep getting `System.Data.DataRow` instead of the value. I need to know, the proper way to store the result(currently I store it in `DataTable`), and to push it into an array.I am newbie in c# ..

```
public void getOutstanding()
{

    SelectQueryBuilder sqbSelect;
    DataSet dsOutstanding;

    sqbSelect = new SelectQueryBuilder();
    sqbSelect.SelectColumns(new string[] { "name"});
    sqbSelect.SelectFromTable("user");
    sqbSelect.AddWhere("category", Comparison.Equals, "18");       

    dsOutstanding = Conn.DataAdapter(CommandType.Text, sqbSelect.BuildQuery());
    sqbSelect = null;

    DataTable areaChart = dsOutstanding.Tables[0];

    for( int a = 0; a < areaChart.Rows.Count; a++) {

       // want to push the value to an array ;       

    }

}
```

Thank you..

Comment: What kind of chart are you using? Usually you can just bind a datatable to a chart like that: chart.DataSource = table; chart.DataBind();

Comment: I am using Chart.js, and it need the data to be in array form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read by using this syntax.

```
string[] array = new string[areaChart.Rows.Count];
for( int a = 0; a < areaChart.Rows.Count; a++) {
   array[a] = areaChart.Rows[a]["name"].ToString();          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access column data by indexing `DataRow` with column name

```
 var names = new string[areaChart.Rows.Count];

 for (var index = 0; index < areaChart.Rows.Count; index++)        
     names[index] = areaChart.Rows[index]["name"].ToString();
```